# How to remove panels from button C#

Tags: c#, winforms, oop

I have created a function that creates a new panel each time a button is pressed, alongside with a button, which should remove the entire panel when pressed.

Here is my code for creating the panels and the button :

```
Panel panel;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            panel = new Panel();
            panel.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(38, 38, 38);
            panel.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(10);
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(panel);
            panel.Show();
            
            Button delbutton = new Button();
            delbutton.Text = "X";
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(delbutton);

            delbutton.Click += new EventHandler(this.ButtonFunction_Click);
        }
```

Considering that every panel created has this `delbutton` , how can i remove the panel of which `delbutton` button was pressed?

I tried to add this method to the button, but it removes panel randomly :

```
void ButtonFunction_Click (Object sender,EventArgs e)
        {

            foreach (Control controlObj in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls)
            {
                flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Remove(controlObj);
                controlObj.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Comment: You should **really** build an UserControl for this. Much simpler to handle the internal functionality and also to layout your Controls consistently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the relevant `Panel` as a `Tag` property of its `Button`, then you can get that in the `Click` handler

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    var panel = new Panel
    {
        BackColor = Color.FromArgb(38, 38, 38),
        Margin = new Padding(10),
    };
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(panel);
    panel.Show();
            
    var delbutton = new Button
    {
        Text = "X",
        Tag = panel,
    };
    delbutton.Click += ButtonFunction_Click;
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(delbutton);
}

private void ButtonFunction_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;
    ((Control)button.Tag).Dispose();
    button.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: If you dispose of a button, how do you think you could cast the `button.Tag`? You may want to do that first and then dispose of the button.

Comment: Should be `var button = (Button)sender; (button.Tag as Control)?.Dispose(); button.Click -= ButtonFunction_Click; button.Dispose();` -- Calling `Remove()` is not necessary, when you dispose of a Control, it's also removed from the `Controls` collection.

Comment: Good point about `Remove`. Why would you need to remove the handler? When it goes out of scope the whole thing is garbage collected anyway?

Comment: Out of what scope? When you add handlers to events in the Designer, the handlers are supposed to exist for the lifetime of the Container Form. When adding/removing Controls at run-time, better not count on garbage collection, you may be disappointed.

Comment: The problem will always be in the opposite case: when adding a handler to a parent container from a child, you *must* remove the handler on dispose, otherwise you leak the child control, because the parent has a longer lifetime. But in the opposite case, there are no more references to the child after it's removed from the parent `Controls` list, so the child gets garbage collected along with the handler reference. I don't see how this could happen in any other way, but I'm happy to be corrected. Is there any way the child could leak without removing the handler?

Comment: @Trevor `Tag` does not actually throw a `ObjectDisposedException` so it would work to do it in that order, nor is it [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.tag?view=netframework-4.8) to do so, although I agree it feels like an implementation detail

Comment: In this simple case? Possibly, yes, the EventHandlerList and its delegates should be collected, at some point. Probably when you close the Form. Do we need to think about it, evaluate each edge case? Profile for a couple of days? Removing the handlers *manually* is no biggie.